# Include a custom font when publishing in Visual Studio XNA

Tags: xna-4.0, fonts, publishing

I have a custom font called "Gold Box Games" that I want to use in a game I'm making. I have the font installed on my computer and it works just fine in the program when I run it in test. However, when I examined the publish settings I noticed I could not include that font with the things the publish-created installer makes.

How do I include a custom font to be pushed along with the rest of my files built with the Publish Wizard? This font will also need to be installed when another user runs my program (installed during that first 'setup' phase when they run the game the first time.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to your in-game fonts, you do not need to install the custom fonts in order to use them with your compiled game.  When compiled, your fonts get converted to .XNB files, which are packaged in in your /bin directory and are used to draw in game.

Comment: Oh! I had no idea. Thanks, that saves me a lot of headache trying to find a solution then :)